# 1,2,3, Next Grid View Page Creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am following a grid view of 1,2,3 Next. [This](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/form-basics) is the tutorial that I am following. But it has this database access as shown below. Actually this tutorial is done by using Web Metric  . And this is accessing the database directly in the cshtml code.

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("xxxxx");
    var selectedData = db.Query("SELECT * FROM yyyy");
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData);
}
```

But my intention is to do the query form using the entity framework. I have already created a separate project for the data access. and I am using that ddl for the data handling. so that I have authority to as shown here. What do you suggest to do for creating a grid view using the entity framework as a separate project.

ps: I am passing a IEnumerable list of objects to the view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly go through this tutorial on Entity Framework.

http://afana.me/post/paging-sorting-and-searching-ef-cf-and-mvc.aspx

When using Entity Framework, now you will be passing the `selectedData` from the controller to your view.

and now your webGrid will use it somewhat like this,

```
var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model.selectedData);
```

Comment: Managed to worked it out on my own.but @Yasser Thanks for the tutorial its a very good one. I will learn a lot